# android kotlin data-binding kapt missing

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to move to kotlin in android, and tried data-binding like this :

```
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_authentication)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application)
            .create<AuthViewModel>(AuthViewModel::class.java)
//mBinding.auth.invoke(viewModel)
        mBinding.auth.invoke(viewModel)
        mBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
```

It gave me can't be invoked as function, so auto-generated this :

```
public void invoke(@NotNull AuthViewModel viewModel) {

    }
...
```

But it keeps saying it's mutable, can be changed by now.

How should I resolve this ?

And gradle file says, I should use kapt, I don't know what is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try initilalizing binding before oncreate by

```
private lateinit var binding : /*your layout name in camelcase*/Binding /*like ActivityMainBinding*/
private lateinit var viewmodel : AuthViewModel
```

then in onCreate

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflator)
viewmodel = ViewModelProvider(this,factory).get(AuthViewModel::class.java)
```

also make sure you added
`buildFeatures { dataBinding true  }` in app gradle file`inside android

Comment: also make sure you added  buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true } in app gradle file